# Unity PropertyDrawer access parent object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class similar to this one:

```
class Foo : MonoBehaviour {
    public Car a;
    [MyProperty]
    public Trunk b;
}
```

I've implemented `MyPropertyAttribute` and a `MyPropertyDrawer` which inherits PropertyDrawer to create custom inspector for MyProperty decorated attributes.

Now, my issues is that I want to access somehow the actual object instance of the class `Foo` who owns that `b` instance.

In other words, I have:

```
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        this._property = property;
        Car c = property.serializedObject.targetObject as Car;
        Foo ownerOfCar = ...; // <<< Idk how to get this instance
    }
```

I want to use the `Foo` reference to change other properties in the class, for example the `b` variable, which's a `Trunk`.

I've tried many properties and methods (like objectReferenceValue, tweaking the serializedObject values etc.) but none really worked :(.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can pass it as an argument to the property drawer, like `[MyProperty(this)] public Trunk b;`. You would need to adapt your property drawer class to accept a Foo argument.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Thanks for your comment. However, as this is an attribute, you can't use the keyword `this` in that context. Thus that won't work.